# CorsFilter cannot be applied to UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource

Tags: spring-boot, cors

Trying to add CorsFilter on my SpringBoot application using @Bean:|

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        registrationBean.setFilter(new CorsFilter(source));
        registrationBean.setOrder(0);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

But i keep getting this error:

**CorsFilter in class org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be.

you are importing CorsFilter from

```
import org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter;
```

and have to import the one of spring with

```
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;
```